# Dutch varchar date issue in SQL server 13 month

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have the following datetime format ( as varchar ) in my database `13-04-2018 1:05:00`.

I need to convert it to the following format: `2018-04-13 01:05:00.` As datetime.

Normal convert functions can't do this because they try to take the 13th month, and that month doesn't exist. This error:

> The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted
>   in an out-of-range value.

Does someone know how to convert this date issue?

Comment: Am I reading a 13th month correctly? by that I mean you want a datetime with a 13th month?

Comment: Yes SQL thinks the 13 (which is the day in my dateformat) is the 13th month thats why it fails.

Comment: so the 13 is actually the day value?

Comment: Your comment on the answer makes it clear what you were after, but the format in your question was not valid for that. I've taken the liberty of editing it, please check to see if you agree.

Answer (score 4):

Using datetimes is always a pain regardless of the language because of all the different formats across the world.

To sort your issue out currently, you need to use a format style which is a third parameter to [CONVERT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql). Personally what I would suggest here is to store as a datetime, because storing datetimes as strings is never a good idea. It just gets too messy later on, but if saved in the format you would like, it would be saved as `yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss`

```
SELECT CONVERT(DATETIME, '13-04-2018 1:05:00',103)
```

You can create your own function to format it in your desired output string.

```
CREATE FUNCTION FormatMyDate
    (@Date DATETIME) RETURNS VARCHAR(20)
AS
BEGIN
    RETURN FORMAT(@Date,'yyyy-dd-MM hh:mm:ss')
END
```

And then you can call it in `SELECT` statements like this:

```
SELECT dbo.FormatMyDate(yourDateCol) 
FROM yourTable
```

Answer (score 0):

this takes the date from the format where month comes before day and reverses the 2 values (month and day)

```
SELECT CONVERT(DATETIME, '2018-13-04 01:05:00', 103);
```

Results:
2018-04-13 01:05:00.000

Comment: updated to be more clear saying format where month location is swapped

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you requirement...

```
SELECT FORMAT(yourdate, 'yyyy-dd-MM')
```

Comment: OP already specified that yourdate was varchar - your suggestion will generate a runtime error. And OP stated the desired output should include the time - which you left out.

Answer (score 0):

Your Solution Bro...

```
DECLARE @d DATETIME = GETDATE()
SELECT FORMAT ( @d, 'MM-dd-yyyy hh:mm:ss', 'de-de' ) AS 'Hoping your result'
```